# SQL CASE statement IS NULL syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement, null, case

I'm very new to SQL and I'm trying to do an IF-statement. Here is my code, hopefully you will be able to spot where the problem is. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT [data1].[Last Name]+", "+[First Name] AS Name, 
       [data1].[User ID], 
       (CASE WHEN [Kla] IS null THEN [Nr] ELSE [Kla]+"-"+[Nr] END) AS [Course Code] 
FROM [data1], [data2]
```

> Syntax error (operator missing) '(CASE WHEN [Kla] IS null THEN [Nr]
>   ELSE [Kla]+"-"+[Nr] END)'

I'm running this in Microsoft Access from two tables (data1 and data2) which I imported from Excel

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Is [Kla] or [Nr] column present in both tables?

Comment: What kind of DB do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I get Syntax error (operator missing) '(CASE WHEN [Kla] IS null THEN [Nr] ELSE [Kla]+"-"+[Nr] END)'.

Comment: [Kla] and [Nr] is only present in [data2]

Comment: Both DBs are tables imported from an excel document. It works without the CASE-statement if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [data1].[Last Name]+", "+[First Name] AS Name, 
[data1].[User ID], 
IIF(ISNULL([Kla]),[Nr],[Kla]+"-"+[Nr]) AS [Course Code]
FROM [data1], [data2]
```

AFAIK, you cannot include NULL checks in a `CASE` statement in Access, so I would suggest you use `IIF` instead.

Comment: how do you provoke this error? When I try to select `columnName + "-" + columnName` I get `Invalid column name '-'` instead of `operator missing`

Comment: That's the error I got too, which is why I added the note about testing it on SQL Server. Invalid column name is the right error because double quotes mark the included content as a column/table name.

Comment: the columnName + "-" + columnName worked before I added the CASE-statement so I don't think thats it.

Comment: What DBMS are you using to do this? In fact, how are you running this query? Please add these details into your question.

Comment: @shree.pat18 ok but your last sentence is a bit confusing then because you explicitly said `My solution is tested on SQL Server also`, which sounds a bit weird if you get a different error than OP ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I agree the phrasing could be better. Will edit. OP still hasn't given more details to actually diagnose the issue though.

Comment: You're welcome. But we would have got there a lot quicker if you had mentioned that you were using Access when you posted your question. Every DBMS has some unique features that may be important in understanding the issue, so you MUST specify the DBMS you are using.

Comment: I did not realize that! I will do that in the future, thanks again!